# OUnit: assert value is instance of type

Tags: unit-testing, ocaml, ounit

Using the [OUnit](http://ounit.forge.ocamlcore.org/api-ounit/OUnit2.html) unit testing framework in OCaml, I would like to test that the result of evaluating a function is an instance of a specified type.

Defining such a test in Python's [PyTest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) would be done as follows:

```
def test_foo():
    assert isinstance(foo(2), int)
```

**How can this logic be translated to OUnit? That is, how are assertions of type membership specified?**

I'm aware that, assuming the function under test is annotated with the proper type signature, this testing might be unnecessary.

Comment: It's also unnecessary if the function is not annotated :-) OCaml is a strongly typed language, you can't compute a value of the wrong type. This is one reason we like it. It of course makes sense to think in terms of *values* that are and aren't allowed.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield. I should have mentioned this earlier, but I can't test for a particular value because the function under test randomly generates instances of a type. I'm really not sure how to unit test such a function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the job of a type checker, and it is made automatically during the compilation (at static time). The type checker (i.e., the compiler) guarantees that all values that are created by a function has the same type, and the type is defined statically at the compilation time. You will not be able to compile a function, that creates values of different types, as you will get a type error during the compilation. This is an essential property of all statically typed languages, e.g., Java, C and C++ also has the same property.

So, probably, you're using are confusing terminology. It might be the case, that what you're actually trying to test, is that the value belongs to a particular variant of a sum type. For example, if you have a sum type called `numbers` defined as:

```
type t = 
  | Float of float
  | Int of int
```

and you would like to test that function `truncate`, defined as

```
 let truncate = function
   | Float x -> Int (truncate x)
   | x -> x
```

always returns the `Int` variant, then you can do this as follows:

```
  let is_float = function Float _ -> true | _ -> false
  let is_int = function Int _ -> true | _ -> false

  assert (is_int (truncate 3.14))
```